# SQL join or Vlookup

Tags: sql, excel

I have a spreadsheet that i have inserted into a table. It is Fedex shipping data and it has a row per package charge. There can numerous charges per package and they will all share a common tracking number.

What i need to do is to create a query, or extract all of the charges per tracking number and have them appear on one line. The number of charges per tracking number can vary from 1 to 8 or 10.

Current table

> TrackingNumber ChargeDescription   ChargeAmount
>   310873570610,   Advancement Fee,    9.32
>   310873570610,   Ontario PST,    2.52
>   310873570610,   Customs Duty,   0.08
>   540310873037854,    Performance Pricing,    -4.35
>   540310873037854,    Fuel Surcharge, 0.73
>   540310873037854,    Earned Discount,    -5.2
>   540310873037861,    Performance Pricing,    -4.06

Needed output

> TrackingNumber, ChargeDescription, ChargeAmount, ChargeDescription, ChargeAmount, ChargeDescription, ChargeAmount
>   310873570610,   Advancement Fee,    9.32, Ontario PST,  2.52, Customs Duty, 0.08 
>   540310873037854,    Performance Pricing,    -4.35, Fuel Surcharge,  0.73, Earned Discount,  -5.2
>   540310873037861,    Performance Pricing,    -4.06

I have tried several different joins as well as many different vlookups in Excel. Any pointer on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: one way that comes to mind is a pivot table that has `TrackingNumber` down the side, `ChargeDescription` across the top, and `ChargeAmount` as the values in the center.  This will also give you a total at the top and sides for each category (how much fuel surcharges have there been / how much was charged to this order)

Comment: Yes this is called a pivot. Do you want to pivot the data out of the table or in the Excel sheet? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with an Excel Macro.

```
Sub RowsToColumns()
Dim r As Range

Set r = Selection
For n = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    If r.Cells(n, 1) = r.Cells(n - 1, 1) And Not IsEmpty(r.Cells(n, 1)) Then
        Range(r.Cells(n, 2), r.Cells(n, 3)).Copy r.Rows(n - 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
        r.Rows(n).Delete
        n = n - 1
    End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Note some caveats here:

1) This version assumes the data is actually formatted as your example data is. Most importantly it assumes that all duplicates are grouped together, so you will want to sort the first column before running this.

2) You MUST select the rows and columns you want to run this against.
[Macro Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlmVV.png)

3) It does not automatically generate column names for new columns created
[Macro After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktcMA.png)

But hopefully this either works for you or puts you on the right path!